# Why linux doesn't search for shared libraries in the same folder

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I know that normally linux search for dynamic libraries in specific folders in the system, like `/lib, /usr/lib/, /usr/local/lib`. And if doesn't find the shared library that is needed by the running program, then it will show an error.

My question is : Why doesn't linux implement the feature to look for libraries in the current folder. Lets say, after searching for the shared library inside all the folders mentioned above, it will search for the shared library inside the current folder before saying that the library wasn't found.

Isn't this feature simple to implement ?? or am I missing something ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding . to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is generally not recommended as it introduces security risk and also makes program behavior less predictable for the end user. If you absolutely want to go down this path and want to avoid explicit setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you can

- link with `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,'$ORIGIN'`
- not call your app directly but rather through a wrapper shell script which would set proper `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and *then* run the app

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are asking is not that hard to implement, but it would be considered a security risk. You can specify a shared library with the help of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

You can find more [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html):

Comment: I heard about the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. But in this case, i have to export the path to that variable in each computer. There is no way that I send the program with the shared library to user and make it run directly by just clicking on the executable.

Comment: In that case you might need to send an installable package based on the target Linux flavour. It would enable setting up the right environment for the executable. Imho it's worth the effort